# How to create a new GitHub repo branch with our System terminal without creating that branch locally in my system

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-for-windows

I am working on a project. I have only the `main` **branch** in my **GitHub repo** and in my **local project**. Now I want to push changes to the new GitHub repo branch `temp` but I do not want to create any new branch for my local project.

I want only one branch for my local project and many branches for my GitHub repo.

Is there any way to create a new GitHub repo branch from the terminal?

If I am running `git branch -M temp`, then after running `git branch -a`, I am getting output as

```
* temp   
remotes/origin/main
```

Does it mean I have only one branch in my local project and its name is changed to `temp`?

But if I am running `git branch temp`, then after running `git branch -a`, I am getting output as

```
* main
  temp
  remotes/origin/main
```

What is the use of `-M` here?

Comment: I have edited the answer to address your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`git push <refspec>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203), you can push a local branch to a different remote branch:

```
git push origin main:test
```

That would update `origin/test` with the commits from local `main`.

---

While a [`git branch -M temp`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--f) would *rename* your local branch main (currently tied to its upstream branch `origin/main`)

That is not what you want. You need to keep your local branch as is (`main`) and push to a different remote branch, as explained above.